# Can't run RPM due to calling hook fsm_file_prepare in selinux plugin on Oracle Linux 9.3

Tags: rpm, oracle-linux

I was doing a standard `yum update` on my Oracle Linux 9.3 system. Unfortunately it rebooted during the update. Now I can't update anything.

I traced it to a problem in RPM. Any time I try to use RPM to install anything it's crashing. I did `rpm -vvvv` and it crashes here:

```
D: create     100644  1 (   0,   0) 26432 COPYING.LESSER;65b45f9e
D: create     100644  1 (   0,   0)  6502 crypto-policies.7.gz;65b45f9e
D: Plugin: calling hook fsm_file_prepare in ima plugin
D: Plugin: calling hook fsm_file_prepare in selinux plugin
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have no idea how to get past this. I could just re-install the entire system (maybe I should do that) but if I could get past this it would be great. I searched and can't find any clear ideas about what causes this.

Comment: Have you rebooted and tried rebuilding the rpm database if the reboot didn't work?

Comment: Yes I did both of those. It's mysterious situation and I'm starting to think I'll need to reinstall the machine.

Comment: Is the RPM database read-only?  Does it have the right permissions?

Comment: I'm not sure. I never could figure out the problem and ended up reinstalling the system.

Answer (score 4):

I hit this problem on Oracle Linux 8.9 server, due to an unpublished Oracle bug which requires a manual workaround.

[Oracle Support Document 3002168.1 - Oracle Linux 8: The dnf install/update Commands Failed with "error: Plugin selinux: hook fsm_file_prepare failed"](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=3002168.1)

Run as root (sudo):

```
rpm -e --nodeps rpm-plugin-selinux
dnf -y install rpm-plugin-selinux
```

Afterwards, I suggest running a [distro-sync](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#distro-sync-command-label) to fix any missing files or broken RPM packages.

Again, run as root (sudo):

```
dnf -y distro-sync
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot! I've lost SSH and sudo and somehow was able to log in into root after tinkering with emergency console (rd.break added to `linux` line in grub, ctrl+x to boot, `mount -o remount,rw /sysroot && chroot /sysroot` afterwards), and reinstalling packages showed errors like `error: lsetfilecon: (-1 sudoedit;65cf6177, system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0) No such file or directory; error: Plugin selinux: hook fsm_file_prepare failed` which was fixed by your proposed fix. Sudo works now as well as SSH, thanks a ton!

Comment: My thanks also Matt. This happened to a headless server, so it was a real pain restoring access. I followed the same process as Dmitry. It was the `fsm_file_prepare` failure that brought me to this SE question/answer.